# Hive: select column with non alphanumeric characters

Tags: json, hive

I'm using Hive 0.13.0, and I was expecting it to work with table and column names having non alphanumerical characters, as said in the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable), but it is not.

I've been able to create a table having column names with dots, for instance:

```
hive> create external table frb_test (recvTime string, fiwareServicePath string, entityId string, entityType string, `ORL.SOU.DH.SSTA10.T.HVAC.HeatLoad` string, `ORL.SOU.DH.SSTA10.T.HVAC.HeatLoad_md` array<struct<name:string,type:string,value:string>>) row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' location '/user/frb/test'; 
OK
Time taken: 0.286 seconds
```

As you can see, I'm using https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde as Json serde.Nevertheless, below is the content of `hdfs:///user/frb/test`:

```
$ hadoop fs -cat /user/frb/test/deleteme
{"recvTime":"2016-02-09T18:03:48.986Z","fiwareServicePath":"orl_sou","entityId":"ORL.SOU.DH.SSTA10","entityType":"ETS", "ORL.SOU.DH.SSTA10.T.HVAC.HeatLoad":"10.673299789428711", "ORL.SOU.DH.SSTA10.T.HVAC.HeatLoad_md":[{"name":"dofTimestamp","type":"ms","value":"2016-02-08T23:00:00.000Z"},{"name":"tag","type":"text","value":"ORL.SOU.DH.SSTA10.T.HVAC.HeatLoad"},{"name":"description","type":"text","value":"Electrical heat load"},{"name":"quality","type":"0:GOOD, +0:ERROR","value":"10813440"},{"name":"max","type":"max","value":"null"},{"name":"min","type":"min","value":"null"},{"name":"lcl","type":"lcl","value":"null"},{"name":"ucl","type":"ucl","value":"null"}]}
```

I'm not able to select the `orl.sou.dh.ssta10.t.hvac.heatload` column:

```
hive> add jar /home/frb/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
hive> select `orl.sou.dh.ssta10.t.hvac.heatload` from frb_test;                                                                                                                    Total jobs = 1                                                                                                                                            
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1455032234756_0008, Tracking URL = http://namenode.fiware.org:8088/proxy/application_1455032234756_0008/
Kill Command = /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1455032234756_0008
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2016-02-11 17:05:56,150 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-02-11 17:06:23,653 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1455032234756_0008 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_1455032234756_0008_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1455032234756_0008

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_1455032234756_0008_m_000000

URL:
  http://namenode.fiware.org:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1455032234756_0008&tipid=task_1455032234756_0008_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:157)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field orl from [0:recvtime, 1:fiwareservicepath, 2:entityid, 3:entitytype, 4:orl.sou.dh.ssta10.t.hvac.heatload, 5:orl.sou.dh.ssta10.t.hvac.heatload_md]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorUtils.getStandardStructFieldRef(ObjectInspectorUtils.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldRef(StandardStructObjectInspector.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.initialize(ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initEvaluators(Operator.java:934)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initEvaluatorsAndReturnStruct(Operator.java:960)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.initializeOp(SelectOperator.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.initializeOp(TableScanOperator.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.initializeOp(MapOperator.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:136)
    ... 22 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

I've seen the Hive property governing how Hive works with regard to the non alphanumeric characters is `hive.support.quoted.identifiers`, which can value `none` (then Hive behaves as 0.12.0 version) or `column`, which I guess it is the default value for 0.13.0; nevertheless, I've tried setting it and no results:

```
hive> set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=column;
hive> select `orl.sou.dh.ssta10.t.hvac.heatload` from frb_test;              
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1455032234756_0009, Tracking URL = http://namenode.fiware.org:8088/proxy/application_1455032234756_0009/
Kill Command = /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1455032234756_0009
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field orl from [0:recvtime, 1:fiwareservicepath, 2:entityid, 3:entitytype, 4:orl.sou.dh.ssta10.t.hvac.heatload, 5:orl.sou.dh.ssta10.t.hvac.heatload_md]
...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that the HQL parser considers the "dot" character as a way to access *the inner fields of a STRUCT*, and nothing else.

And I would bet that among all the people involved in the support of "quoted identifiers" in Hive, no-one ever thought of a test case with a "dot" in a column name. After all, who on earth would be crazy enough to use a "dot" in a column name??

OK, maybe. Then who would be crazy enough to define a STRUCT column with a "dot" in its name, out of perversity, just to add an extra "dot" in the mix??

OK, let's assume this might happen. Then would that hypothetical person push the perversity even further, by insisting on using the first ever version of Hive that did support "quoted identifiers"? With no battle-testing of that feature in actual production systems? And no chance to benefit from eventual bug fixes??

**My 2 cents:** since you clearly have no control on that junk JSON you receive, just run a fast `sed` on it *(or a slow Java regular expression, if you wish)* to replace these dotted monstruosities with sane column names. And be happy ever after.

Comment: Ah, by the way: there are different people developing different parts of Hive. As a result, the semantics of  `CREATE` and `ALTER` commands are not consistent (just try to run "alter table SomeDB.SomeTable ..." and see what happens). So it should not be a surprise that something supported in `CREATE` may not work in a `SELECT`.

Comment: It would be fairly easy to add an option to the serde, something like using underscores instead of periods in the column names, so if you create a table with a column "ORL_SOU_DH_SSTA10_T_HVAC_HeatLoad", it  would look for  "ORL.SOU.DH.SSTA10.T.HVAC.HeatLoad". Why don't you file an issue in the serde's github - I am actually the creator of the serde

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter, I'm aware of all the problems you mention, nevertheless the Hive version and the Json data have been imposed in this project, thus I have to go with them :( I already proposed to replace the dots with underscores in the stored data at HDFS, then I did the same with the column names. The tests were good, but the problem was the original data was altered and that was not accepted by the project. Thanks for your support!

Comment: @Roberto Congiu Many many thanks! It would be great if the parser does such kind of translation. I'll fire that issue right now.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I can't really change the parsers, but changing the serde should be pretty easy, I'll see if I can get it done this weekend.

Comment: By the way, in the meanwhile you could try using the mapping option of the serde, (see https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde#mapping-hive-keywords)  adding something like mapping.heatload ="orl.sou.dh.ssta10.t.hvac.heatload" and changing the column name to heatload should do the trick

Comment: Just pushed changes to handle this. See https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde#mapping-names-with-dots